# You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz for plot_model to work

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, graphviz, pydot

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

('You must install pydot (`pip install pydot`) and install graphviz (see instructions at https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) ', 'for plot_model/model_to_dot to work.')
I have already installed the packages and still it is not working, I tried to uninstall and re-install but it didn't help.

```
import pydot
import pydotplus
import graphviz
```

strangely when I import the packages in the cell just above it works fine and gives no error, how can I solve this issue?
TIA

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you work it around?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my PC is Windows. So I downloaded Graphviz for windows on the [GraphViz website](https://www.graphviz.org/download/) AND downloaded it with PIP, then it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).